# ゲームアプリで使用するメディアファイル（画像、動画、音楽）の圧縮方法

Tags: python, pygame

私はpythonのライブラリpygameでゲームアプリを作っています
ざっくりですが、画像ファイルのほかに動画ファイル（MP4）、音楽ファイル（ogg）を大量に使う想定のゲームです
肝心のゲーム部分はおおよそできてきたのですが、容量が膨大になる懸念が出てきたのでファイル圧縮をしたいと思っています

ただ、ご存知の通りMP4などのすでに圧縮しているファイル形式ではzipやrarで圧縮しても容量は変わらないため、解決できずに困っています
「動画ファイル　圧縮」などで検索しても、画素数を下げる（質を下げる）ツールなどしか見当たりませんでした…
見た目や音質などにはこだわりたいので、ファイルの質を下げるようなことはしたくありません

このようなメディアファイルを大量に使うアプリの場合、どのように対応するのがよろしいでしょうか…
是非助力ください

Answer (score 2, accepted):

同じフォーマットの中であれば画質とサイズは完全なトレードオフの関係なので画質はそのままでサイズだけ下げたいというのはあり得ません。

単純にファイルサイズを小さくするならより圧縮率の高くなるフォーマットを使うぐらいしかありません。

ところで「ファイルサイズを小さくする」は手段であって、目的や実現しなければならないことそのものではないはずです。

例えば「ストレージの占有率を下げる」という目的であればオンデマンドでファイルをダウンロードするという手法も考えられます(ただし当然考えることは増えます)

アプリケーションの中身について全く説明がないので具体的な回答はしようがありませんが。